# HTML code disappears in String iOS

Tags: iphone, html, ios, xcode, string

I am parsing `XML` file with RSS from an URL. In the `XML`, there is a tag as description.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://www.ipadia.co/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/sayfada-bul-150x150.png" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="sayfada bul" title="sayfada bul" />Yine çok kişinin dikkatinden kaçan ama faydalı bir araç Bulunduğunuz sayfada arama yapmak bazen çok gerekli olabiliyor Bunun için google arama tabınıkullanacağız Google aramatab ına tıklayin Resimdeki gibi Arama listesinin sonunda bu sayfada bul çıkacak Arama yapmak istediğiniz kelimeyi yazın &#8230; <a href="http://www.ipadia.co/bulundugunuz-sayfada-arama-yapmak/">Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&#8594;</span></a>
]]>
</description>
```

I am using this code as `NSString`. As you see, there is an image link at the beginning of description tag. I want to take the image link from this string. But when I parse this, It is giving me just the text, not HTML code. When I write this with `NSLog`, I can't see the image link in it. In short, `Xcode` doesn't give me the HTML code in the string.

I tried to load this code in `UIWebView` assuming that it can show the image. But the image didn't be shown in WebView either. Just the text was displayed.

When I look the RSS in browser, I can see the image code in it, but in Xcode, I can't see HTML code, it just gives me the plain text. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: I think the `CDATA` may cause the issue. How can I challenge with that?

These are my `XMLParser` methods.

```
    -(void) parser: (NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement: (NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

{


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"])
        if (!ItemA)
        {
            ItemA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }



    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
        // NSLog(@"ITEM OLUŞTURULDU.");
        anItem= [[Item alloc] init];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if (!currentElementValue)

        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];

    else

        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    // NSLog(@"PRCOSSING VALUE :%@", currentElementValue);
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{


    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"channel"])
        return;

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        // NSLog(@"qqqqqq:%@", anItem.title);


        [ItemA addObject:anItem];

        counter++;

        // NSLog(@"kkk:%i", ItemA.count);
        // NSLog(@" -*-*-*-*-* COUNTER: %d",counter);
        anItem = nil;
        return;
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"])
    {
        anItem.title=currentElementValue;
        // NSLog(@"kkk-title:%@", anItem.title);
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"])
    {
        anItem.description=currentElementValue;
        // NSLog(@"kkkkkk-desc:%@", anItem.description);
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
    {
        anItem.link=currentElementValue;
        // NSLog(@"kkkkkk-link:%@", anItem.link);
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
    {

        anItem.pubDate=currentElementValue;
        // NSLog(@"kkkkkk-pubdate:%@", anItem.pubDate);
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"])
    {

        anItem.category=currentElementValue;
        // NSLog(@"kkkkkk-category:%@", anItem.category);
    }


    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

Comment: First of all `Xcode` has nothing to do with your problem..

Comment: Secondly whatever you have tried show us some come

Comment: I added my ´parse´ codes in the question. I think the CDATA may cause the problem while parsing. But I haven't found any solutions yet.

Comment: try a different xml parser, the xml looks fine.